# What does a single quote (') mean in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In an OVM example class, I see the following statement in the constructor:

```
void'(get_config_int("num_packets", this.num_packets));
```

What is the first part `void'(` supposed to be doing in this statement?

Comment: you're tagging your questions with both Verilog and SystemVerilog, but they're not relevant to Verilog. Different language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case the single quote is used for type casting. The `void'()` in `void'(get_config_int("num_packets", this.num_packets));` means to ignore the return value from `get_config_int`.

A good simulator should give a warning if a function or a expression return value is not assigned to anything. Using `void'()` explicitly tells the tool that you wish to ignore the return value and not see the warning.

You can can use other casts too, such as `int'()`, `MyPredefinedStruct'()`, `9'()`. note that giving a constant in casting will return a bit vector. `9'(4'b0101) == 9'b000_0101`

See the IEEE Std 1800-2012 and read section 6.24 for more explanations and examples.